# How can I place buttons at the end of a ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-relativelayout

I am having a problem with my layout screen. What I am trying to achieve is a listview with multiple rows, each row having one Image view and two `EditText` views. At the bottom of the very last row, there should be two buttons (<kbd>Submit</kbd> & <kbd>Cancel</kbd>)

I have managed to get the row working successfully, but when adding the buttons I keep getting errors. The data is being read in from a cursor, which I find complicates things further.

Is there a way I can use a row layout inside a `contentView` layout?

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/gm" >
</ImageView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="email"        
    >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/logo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/firstLine"
    android:text="password"  
    >
</EditText></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What if you surround the entire ListView with a LinearLayout (with orientation "vertical") and then place the two buttons inside a nested LinearLayout with orientation "horizontal"?

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate layout with the bottom buttons and add it as a [footer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29). You can also add a header btw.